# How to handle a listbox keydown event in the viewmodel to delete listItems?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a listbox how do i handle the keydown event in the corresponding view model of the page to delete listItems?
I have using this cod in view:

```
<ListBox Margin="2,25,2,2" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CardViewModelSearchResults}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCategoryViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ff:TextBoxBehaviour.TextChangedCommand="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.TextChanged}" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal" BorderThickness="0" AllowDrop="False" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryID}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add KeyBinding to your application or specifically to your ListBox.

## ListBox

```
<ListBox Margin="2,25,2,2" Grid.Row="3"  ItemsSource="{BindingPath=CardViewModelSearchResults}" 
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCategoryViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=MyDeleteCommand}" />
            </ListBox.InputBindings>
    </ListBox>
```

You need to use Command reference if you are using .net 3.5 in .net4.0 this works fine

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using an  [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) instance in your ViewModel that will delete the item from the ListBox. To route the KeyDown event to the command is a more tricky thing. I suggest looking at [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)'s `EventToCommand` behavior (you can implement this yourself if you dont want to use the framework).

Alternatively, handle the keydown event in your View's code behind and then invoke the command from there.